# Getting Error when finding frequency of characters in string using tree map in java

Tags: java, treemap

```
I am trying to find out the frequency of characters in string using java tree map. Everything is going fine .But extra lin of string is getting added when i am getting output for one particlar case .


import java.awt.Menu;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Main {
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the input string");
    String s1=s.nextLine();

    Map<Character,Integer> map=new TreeMap<Character,Integer>();

    for(int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++){
       char c = s1.charAt(i);
       Integer val = map.get(new Character(c));
       if(val != null){
         map.put(c, new Integer(val + 1));
       }else{
         map.put(c,1);
       }
    }           

    for(Map.Entry<Character,Integer> en:map.entrySet()){
        int count=en.getValue();
        System.out.printf("%c : ",en.getKey());
        for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
        System.out.printf("*");

        System.out.printf("\n");
    }


    }
}
```

for Input: Kohli is the man of the match

this should be the output
K : * 
a : ** 
c : * 
e : ** 
f : * 
h : **** 
i : ** 
l : * 
m : ** 
n : * 
o : ** 
s : * 
t : ***

but am getting this:
 :****** 
K :* 
a :** 
c :* 
e :** 
f :* 
h :**** 
i :** 
l :* 
m :** 
n :* 
o :** 
s :* 
t :***

How to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 6 whitespaces in the string you entered. That's why you get this output. A whitespace is a character too.

If you want to remove this whitespaces, you can update your code like this:

```
String s1=s.nextLine().replaceAll(" ","");
```